# Input not grabbing correct coordinate libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a mining game where if you click somewhere you will delete the block laying there. All blocks right now are just squares and are only drawn if the spot in my 2d boolean array is true. So I am trying to take the position and set it to false wherever you click here is the touchdown method of my `inputprocessor`

```
    private Vector2 tmp = new Vector2();
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    tmp.x = screenX / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE;
    tmp.y = screenY / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE;
    cam.unproject(new Vector3(tmp.x, tmp.y, 0));
    grid.manipulateGrid((int)(tmp.x), (int)(tmp.y), false);
    System.out.println("Clicked at: (" + tmp.x + ", " + tmp.y +")");
    return false;
}
```

I am also translating the camera to my players position. The `grid.manipulateGrid` takes an x and a y and sets it to false. My player is located at  (10, 126) in grid coordinates and when I click next to him it says I am clicking at (35, 24) I am not sure if I am doing this right but I have been really searching everywhere and can't find a solution. I have found questions similar but to not result. If someone can tell me how to adjust the click to the coordinates of the player I would be incredibly appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to divide the mapgrid after unprojecting it

```
    @Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    tmp.x = screenX;
    tmp.y = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY);
    tmp.z = 0;
    cam.unproject(tmp);
    grid.manipulateGrid((int)(tmp.x) / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE, (int)(tmp.y) / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE, false);
    System.out.println("Clicked at: (" + tmp.x / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE + ", " + tmp.y / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE +")");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the coordinates of drawing are not the same of input. The coordinates of input in  LibGDX start from the upside-left corner as (0,0) and the coordinates of the world in general where you draw and all that start downside-left. So you need to do something like:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    tmp.x = screenX / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE;
    tmp.y = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY)/ MapGrid.CELL_SIZE;
    cam.unproject(new Vector3(tmp.x, tmp.y, 0));
    grid.manipulateGrid((int)(tmp.x), (int)(tmp.y), false);
    System.out.println("Clicked at: (" + tmp.x + ", " + tmp.y +")");
    return false;
}
```

For more information read this:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103145/libgdx-input-y-axis-flipped

Comment: Have you printed the MapGrid.CELL_SIZE variable? Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: I am 100% sure it is correct and I just printed it as well and it is

Comment: do you mean unprojecting?

Comment: No, I mean something like this               camera.viewportWidth = V_WIDTH;
  camera.viewportHeight = V_WIDTH*((float)height/width);
  V_HEIGHT = (int)camera.viewportHeight;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92758/discussion-between-luke-and-jose-romero).